# Access elements of map which is member of vector without creating copy

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have following data type

```
typedef     std::map <std::string.std::string> leaf; 
typedef     std::map <std::string,leaf> child;
typedef     std::vector<child> parent;
```

Now if I want access parent element at index 0 and child element having key "x" and then perform some operation of it's values

First way of doing this will be like:

```
    parentobject[0]["x"]["r"]
```

But every time I need to repeat these index whenever I want access that value.

Second way of doing this will be like:
       std::string value=parentobject[0]["x"]["r"]
Then use value object. But problem with this approach is this line will create copy of the string.

Is there a better way to access variable without creating copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reference to avoid copy:

```
std::string & value = parentobject[x][y][z];
```

Or, will you be okay with this instead:

```
//define a lambda in the scope
auto get =  [] (int x, std::string const & y, std::string const & z) 
      -> std::string &
{
    return parentobject[x][y][z];
}

//then use it as many times as you want in the scope
std::string & value = get(0, "x", "r");

get(1, "y", "s") = "modify";
```

Comment: What's the value of that function, aside from potentially adding the overhead of a function call? You still have to specify all the arguments and all you've done is hidden the object they're looked-up from.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Nothing great, just doing the same thing differently, some people like it. And a little advantage you have here : you can easily change the name `parentobject` to `grandparentobject` when the project gets too old.

Comment: @VivekGoel: Any problem with my answer?

Comment: @Nawaz 
I think first answer was having problem. In that function was assuming name of parentobject and it's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use a reference:

```
const std::string& value = parentobject[0]["x"]["r"];
```

Now you can refer to `value` anywhere you like (within the same block scope) without having to perform the map lookups again.

Remove the `const` if you *really* need to.

Please purchase and read one of [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) in order to learn C++'s basic features.

Comment: link broken to the books

Comment: @blueskin: Thanks; link replaced :)